# Is there any way to see the options for the next directory on a cd command?

Tags: command-line

When I cd to a/b/c, sometimes I want to see what are the children dirs of c. Normally, I would do it like this

```
cd a/b/c
ls
child1 child2   
cd child1
```

Is there any way to investigate the children without stopping to do the ls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `cd a/b/c` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> several times. It works with Bash if you enable the completion.

Comment: I guess I want a preview of that command before I hit return

Comment: @akh2103, ok sorry. See my updated answer.

Comment: `cd`-completion, if correctly configured, will only show you the child _dirs_. The `ls` command in your question would show all files.

Comment: @alexis can you link me how to configure this?

Comment: @alexis this works out-of-the-box on `bash` and (IIRC) on `zsh`.

Comment: @strugee it depends on your distro. It's not built into the shell, it's an addon. Some distros just include it by default.

Comment: @Patrick really? I didn't know that.

Comment: @strugee, look for `/etc/bash_completions` being loaded from your `.bashrc` (or perhaps indirectly from a system `rc` file).